# Query remote hive tables from local spark 2x program

Tags: apache-spark, exception, hive, apache-spark-sql

When I run a local spark2x program from eclipse, I am getting belo error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: When hive.metastore.uris is setted, please set spark.sql.authorization.enabled and hive.security.authorization.enabled to true to enable authorization.;

Code used:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:/winutils");
//kerberos releated
val ZKServerPrincipal = "zookeeper/hadoop.hadoop.com";
val ZOOKEEPER_DEFAULT_LOGIN_CONTEXT_NAME = "Client";
val ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_PRINCIPAL_KEY = "zookeeper.server.principal";
val hadoopConf: Configuration = new Configuration(); 
LoginUtil.setZookeeperServerPrincipal(ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_PRINCIPAL_KEY, ZKServerPrincipal);
LoginUtil.login(userPrincipal, userKeytabPath, krb5ConfPath, hadoopConf);
//creating spark session    
val spark = SparkSession .builder() .appName("conenction").config("spark.master", "local") .config("spark.sql.authorization.enabled","true") .enableHiveSupport() .getOrCreate() 
    val df75 = spark.sql("select * from dbname.tablename limit 10")
```

Comment: Copied core-site.xml,hbase-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,hive-site.xml,mapred-site.xml,yarn-site.xml to classpath from remote cluster.

Comment: Instead of putting in comment, try to edit your question properly

Comment: are you able to ping your nodes from local? The error clearly mentions that you need to try set spark.sql.authorization.enabled and hive.security.authorization.enabled to true to enable authorization. Why dont you try these steps before posting the question.